# I have PHP populating a Dropdown box, and I want it to also populate two read only Text boxs from the same Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called Parts, (PartID, PartName, Cost) and I have PHP populating a Drop down box with the PartID's. I want it to when a user selects a Part ID, it populates one text box with the Part's name and the other box, with the Part's cost.
 Here's what my Code look's like for the drop down box if it helps any :)

```
$sql = "SELECT PartID FROM Parts WHERE PartID LIKE 'C0%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PartID'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['PartID'] . "'>" . $row['PartID'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're exactly trying to do, but this sounds more like javascript, to me.

Set a onchange function on your dropdown and get it to fill the fileds with name and cost that you would have stock into a javascript array before. Sounds ugly but it would work

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to POST back to retrieve the values, either with a simple POST or an AJAX POST

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

$partid = $_GET["PartID"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID = '$partid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$part_name = $row ["PartName"];
$part_cost = $row ["PartCost"];
}

$sql = "SELECT PartID FROM Parts WHERE PartID LIKE 'C0%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PartID' onchange='document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['PartID'] . "'>" . $row['PartID'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<input type='text' value='$part_name' />";
echo "<input type='text' value='$part_cost' />";
```