# I am trying to have a drop down box that is populated through mySQL and PhP, populate two read only boxes, with PartName and Cost

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to have a drop down box that is populated through mySQL and PhP, populate two read only boxes, with PartName and Cost. The drop down box get's populated with the correct choices, and then when I choose a choice from that. My Parts table has these 3 columns: PartID, PartName, Cost. it doesn't populate the read only boxes Here's what the code looks like:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {  

$partid = $_GET["PartID"];  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID = '$partid'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  

$part_name = $row ["PartName"];  
$part_cost = $row ["Cost"];  
}

$sql = "SELECT PartID FROM Parts WHERE PartID LIKE 'C0%'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  

echo "<select name='PartID' onchange='document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();'>";  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   
{  
echo "<option value='" . $row['PartID'] . "'>" . $row['PartID'] . "</option>";  
}  
echo "</select>";  

echo "<input type='text' value='".$part_name."' />";  
echo "<input type='text' value='".$part_cost."' />";
```

Comment: you can't write to read-only boxes?

Comment: @Orbit When I moved this over to the server to try out the code, drop down boxes become populated with the proper results, but when I select one of the choices, None of the Read only boxes become populated.

Comment: You need to sanitize your inputs, or you're going to be wide open for SQL Injection. Also, you seem to be using `$_GET` -and- `$_POST`..

Comment: @Orbit Yes I could, I was just trying to prevent the user from editing the information that is being posted, I'll give that a try, and see what it results in.

Comment: Just curious if it will work, or if it is a problem with the logic.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could mark the answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196570/i-have-php-populating-a-dropdown-box-and-i-want-it-to-also-populate-two-read-onl/5196681#5196681

Comment: @jnpcl could you explain a little more what you mean by the $_GET -and- $_POST @Orbit I tried making them not read only and the boxes still show up empty.

Comment: @Donnie: `if (!empty($_POST)) { $partid = $_GET["PartID"];` -- If your form's `action` is `GET`, then `$_POST` will be empty. If the form's `action` is `POST`, then `$_GET` will be empty. Pick one.

Comment: @cusimar9 for some reason it is now allowing me to mark the answer, I asked that question from a different computer, and I don't remember if I logged in or not. Is there another way for me to mark the answer? (I'm new to Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *form1* contains the select box, when the page is submitted, you ar checking if $_POST is not empty, but then taking values from $_GET. If your form posts, then both the check and assignment need to come from the $_POST array, otherwise, both need to come from the $_GET array.